# Can I use relays for heating element?

Tags: microcontroller, relay, heater

I know that relays are used for heating element or any electronic other device with high wattage/high current. But for my application, I am using a Nichrome wire as a heating element and only want to provide power of 100mW, for that I need a current of approximately 71mA current(which I already calculated). I will be using a microcontroller to control it and will be turning it on and off at regular intervals. I was planning to use BJTs as my current driver circuits but then someone suggested me about relays. The maximum current that the MCU pin can provide is 50mA. I could only find applications with high wattage that use relays for example in automotive applications. Can someone suggest me if using relays would work for my application? Or if they would work which I think they will, would it be better than using BJT as a current driving circuit?

Comment: At those power levels, probably.  But a MOSFET would be perfect (and quiet) and a BJT would still be tolerable.

Comment: To put things in perspective, the coil of a typical e-commerce relay requires a current not unlike that which your load requires, and is more inductive.  So it's almost harder to drive the relay, than to directly drive your load.

Comment: We cannot answer with certainty if you can drive the relay directly from the MCU - for that you need to check the control current (or voltage and resistance of the driving coil). Generally speaking, it can work. Is it a great idea? No. If you are looking for isolation, it would make more sense to use an optocoupler

Comment: 100mW is not "high wattage"   It's not even "low wattage".  It's "trivial wattage".   You don't need to use relays unless you need electrical isolation.

Comment: I would probably use a MOSFET. But a BJT will work fine, too, as long as you drive the base with at least 3 mA or so to get it into saturation.

Comment: You might be able to find a small relay that will work. But I don't see any benefit in using a relay for this application.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry, I didn't quite understand your point "...and is more inductive". Do you mean that due to the low current, the relay itself won't be able to turn on? But I read about solid state relays which require a very low current to turn on, since they don't have any coils.

Comment: @mkeith thanks for suggesting. However I want to know the reason that why you would probably not use relays.

Comment: I think the relay will be more expensive, larger, might click when it switches, will probably wear out sooner/faster, and many relays will dissipate almost as much power in the coil as your entire  load. Solid state relays are not relays. They are semiconductor switches. A simple inexpensive transistor will do the job and be very reliable for a long time. The nichrome will probably fail before the transistor does.

Comment: @KyleB I also read about relays being used where there is requirement of electrical isolation. However I didn't quite get the point. I know that electrical isolation means that when two circuits are having different operating voltages and they need to run using their own voltage source even though when connected using relay or something similar. But when I would be using a BJT or MOS, I would still need to use a voltage source apart from the voltage source that my MCU would use. Wouldn't that be called as an electrical isolation? Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Thanks

Comment: Isolation can be required for safety. If you use an arduino or something to switch a 120V or 240V circuit, a relay can help guarantee that your arduino does not become energized at line voltage, which could shock you. The relay outputs are completely isolated from the inputs. There needs to be guaratneed isolation between line voltage and anything that will be handled by a person to avoid shocks. If your heating element runs on something 50V or less, it shouldn't be necessary to use isolation for safety. If you use a transistor, most likely MCU ground and heating element ground are connected.

Comment: 'isolation' here means no direct metal or other conducting material connection between circuits

Comment: Just use a logic-level MOSFET such as A03400 which can turn on nicely with only 2.5V. And I *seriously* doubt your MCU pin can deliver 50mA safely or reliably. Check your calculations too- if you have only 1.4V for the heater the MCU will not likely run from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered in the comments which I am going to summarize here: As @mkeith and @KyleB have mentioned that relays won't provide any advantage unless there is a requirement of electrical isolation. Further as @ChrisStratton mentioned, it is harder to drive relays.
A better solution would be to use MOSFETs/BJTs as most of the comments suggest and another way is to follow answer by @TonyStewartEE75.

Answer (score 1):

A PWM transistor switch can regulate the average current, or you can choose a better uC such as a PIC12 that supports max. current out of low 200 mA  or 150 mA high.

100mW @ 71mA = 1.4V  or 20 Ohms  choose duty cycle from 1.4/Vdd supply voltage ratio and add a flyback diode for wire inductance.

ZTX450 NPN. 200~300 Ohm base drive from 3V, PWM 40%.

Comment: Note: Relays do not PWM very well at cycles under x minutes. The avalanche rated MOSFET is your best choice then fast PWM cycles are no problem and no diodes. It appears you are using a single cell battery at just less than 1.5V. The BJT will have a forward CE voltage drop of either 0.7 or 1.4 volts, not leaving much for the nichrome wire.

Comment: I did not suggest any relays and a ZTX450 drops only 20mV @ 71 mA ($0.81).  (Rce<0.3 ohms) while A  low threshold FET with 1.5V needs a Vt= about 0.7V to have this resistance to conduct well at 1.5V, These ONLY come in SMD packages and cost about the same with about the same performance.  Rb for the BJT needs to conduct about 7mA. or ~R= 2.3V/7m~300 ohms  and with PWM controls the average current to be the correct temperature.